# Screenshot command Discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

First of all, I'm a new guy here and this is my first question, so I'd like to request y'all to ignore any flaws or unexpected details in this question.

So I'm trying to make a *screenshot* command for my Discord.py bot and currently I'm struck with the following code fragment:

```
async def ss(ctx, site):
    embed=discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.orange(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_image(url=(f"https://image.thum.io/get/width/1920/crop/675/maxAge/1/noanimate/{site}"))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

However, the bot just sends an empty embed even for a valid URL. Currently, what seems the most obvious to me is that Discord isn't able to recognize this as a valid image as it doesn't end in a image extension like .png or .jpeg, and hence the empty embed.

TBH I don't know any alternate code for what I'm trying to achieve. I searched a lot and I think it's something to do with BytesIO but I don't have the slightest idea on how to achieve this using the module.

What I'm expecting at this point of time is two things:

1. Fix the current flaw so that I'm able to send the screenshot of the desired website.
2. Report to the message author if the website is invalid, in the sense that there's no website on the specified domain, or that the request timed out due to delayed response on the website's end.

Thus, I'd like to request the community to help me out with my goal on this command. I'm not asking to be spoon-fed, but this is the only command in my bot till now, for which I don't have the slightest idea how to fix it. I'd like to thank everyone for their considerate reply in advance.

Hearty regards,
Sayan Bhattacharyya.

Comment: It looks like you have an unmatched parenthesis on the `set_image` line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's my bad, since I'm using my phone, that happened while copying and pasting the code fragment. That's actually correct in my bot's code. Still, the embed is sent empty.

Comment: Do you have an example `site` for which this code should work?

Comment: Yes sure, take for example, StackOverFlow itself, like this: https://image.thum.io/get/width/1920/crop/675/maxAge/1/noanimate/https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Your site does not redirect to a valid image file and doesn't end with a good image extension.

So this **is not** a Discord problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and debugging on my end and found that the thing doesn't work with URLs that don't have HTTPS:// or HTTP:// in front of them. If I use a link that has them, it works fine

**So now what you have to do**

- See if user has used http:// or https:// in the start of the link

```py
if not site.startswith("https://", "http://"):
    # site doesn't start with http:// or https://
    site = "https://" + site # we add https in front of the URL
```

- See if the link is valid

```py
# add this at the top of your file
import re

# define this variable somewhere outside of the command
URL_REGEX = re.compile(r"http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+")

# then in your command, use
if not re.fullmatch(URL_REGEX, site):
    # URL is invalid, send a message here
    await ctx.send("Invalid URL")
    return 
    # the `return` here stops the command from running after sending the message
```